# Pre-filter in Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

How can I apply a non interactive default filter to Tablefilter?

Something like `show rows where field_1="variable"` but stablished by default when the table is loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: What filtering addons are you using?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, sorry. I am using Tablesorter standard Filter Widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you can set the header class to `"filter-false"` to disable the filter in that column; then [set the desired filters](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#setfilters) after the table [initializes](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#initialized) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/785/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blackice',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    initialized: function (table) {
        $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['abc'], true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am struggling with the combination of .csvtotable, .bind and .set filters. Would you please take a look at my code? [http://pastebin.com/xVQhCKH0]

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.10.8, another solution would be to add the desired filter to the header column's `data-value` attribute (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062549).)

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      ...
      <th data-value="abc">...</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

More information and a sample can be found on the [Custom Filter Widget Functions](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html) demo.