# Tablesorter: Set initial filter-select value on load

Tags: filter, load, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter table where a column uses the `filter-select` and `filter-onlyAvail` classes.
What I'm trying to do is pre-filter that column on one of the values in the drop-down select.

I have tried setting it in the `data-placeholder` attribute but that doesn't do the trick.

I've also tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.tablesorter.setFilters($("#table"),['','','','','','','','T'],true);
});
```

It correctly sets the filter in the select menu but doesn't actually RUN the filter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To initially set the filters, add the filter to a header `"data-value"` attribute (set by the [`filter_defaultAttrib` widget option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#filter-default-attrib)):

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      ...
      <th data-value="T">...</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can [see an example here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html) in the Age column where `<30` is initially set.

Comment: Thanks Mottie!
Not sure how I missed that in the documentation.